# why I cannot call outside function from $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

With below code, click on button doesn't call handleData() function,
if I use anonymous function way (which inside the /* */), it worked.

Can someone explain what the problem is? and how to fix it?
I want to call global function from $(document).ready(...).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function handleData(data, status) {
        $("#p1").text(data);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function() {
            $.get("testAsync?name=value", handleData(data, status));
        });

        /*
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.get("testAsync?name=value", function(data, status) {
                $("#p1").text(data);
            });
        });
         */
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Send an HTTP GET</button>
    <p id="p1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because it expects a function and not a function call. If handleData returned a function it would work too

Answer (score 5):

The function is being called immediately because you have `(arguments)` after it.

Since the arguments are in order, just pass `handleData` alone.

Answer (score 4):

Change the function call from

```
$.get("testAsync?name=value", handleData(data, status));
```

to

```
$.get("testAsync?name=value", handleData);
```

In the first case you are immediately executing the function.. Just pass in the function pointer and it will work as expected..

Comment: @huican .. Glad to have helped :)